# Opacity option with Fill in Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to fill two overlapped regions using `fill` and `pattern`. My problem is that the opacity option is not working in my example:

```
 \begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.85]
    \begin{axis}
        [ticks=none,
        ymin=0,ymax=1.7,
        xmin=0,xmax=1.7]      
    \addplot[pattern=dots,mark=*] coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (0,1.3)
                (1.1,1.1)
                (1.3,0)
                (0,0)   
    };
    \addplot[fill=green,fill opacity=0.2,mark=*] coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (0,1.3)
                (1.3,0)
                (0,0)    };
     \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}   `
```

which produces the follwing figure:

[image]

I need to reduce the opacity of the green region.

Comment: It works for me. Which version of `pgfplots` do you use? Please try updating.

Comment: @HarishKumar I updated all the packages (in Miktex) but still have the same problem. For the `pgfplots` version, I found in the text file: `Package: pgfplots 2015/05/02 v1.12.1 Data Visualization (1.12.1)`.

Comment: I too have the same version but it works: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jQPX1.png  Can you show the full code please.

Comment: Might also be a viewer issue. I know my slightly old version of evince doesn't always get this right, but double checked in Adobe Reader things look as they should.

Comment: I just found the source of this problem.. Actually it was because of the `transparent` package that I was putting in the preamble.  Any idea why ? Anw thank you for your time!

Comment: @tam That's why you need to write a full example in the question. :) You don't need this `transparent` package with `pgfplots`, you can remove it.

Comment: (I'm voting to close this question as duplicate because the debug part is done in the comment and the reason is given in @Heiko Oberdiek's asnwer)

Answer (score -2):

i had the same error and could reduce it to the following package: `fixmetodonotes`. 
This interfered with transparency.

By adding

```
\usepackage{fixmetodonotes}
```

to the above example, transparency got lost.